# Strange "uneditable" symbols on specific linebreaks in vim, Debian 10 (Pic)

Tags: debian, terminal, vim

In all files I open with vim, I see a strange `1/2` symbol showing up on the second line, but only if the second line contains a unix linebreak. It *always* appears on line 2 of the file. The character is neither editable nor selectable.

I'm using a fresh vanilla Debian 10 install with no modifications to any vimrc files and no `.vimrc` in my user dir. Actually I just created my `.vimrc` file and it made no difference.

See pic:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I'm now also seeing `;?;?` at the beginning of all new files and files that begin with an empty unix linebreak. Like the `1/2` symbol, these characters are neither editable nor selectable.

In the below pic, deleting the leading empty line will cause the `;?;?` to disappear and `1/2` to reappear on an empty line 2 after closing/reopening the file.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Answering questions from the comments:

1. [Here is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2styi7AF) of `od -cx /etc/apt/sources.list`, the source of the first screenshot.
2. My terminal software is [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/), with setting in options `Terminal > Emulation = Xterm`. These extra characters do not appear when using a vanilla version of PuTTY.
3. The output of vim's `:help startup-terminal|set term` is `term=xterm`.
4. My locale from `cat /etc/default/locale` = `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: Two important things for answerers here are missing from the question: what terminal emulator is in use and what VIM thinks the terminal type to be.

Comment: `:help startup-terminal|set term`, and your terminal emulator is _either_ XTerm _or_ SecureCRT.  It cannot be both.  They are two different softwares.  If it's SecureCRT, then you also need to tell answerers what emulation you have chosen to set it to.

Comment: The output of `:help startup-terminal|set term` is `term=xterm`. My terminal software is SecureCRT. Inside its' settings is a section called Terminal > Emulation = Xterm.

Comment: I suspect that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/ciKI2MXoww4/Zi6UuVwCCQAJ gives further clues, and that you'll discover that this doesn't happen if you pick "Linux" as the emulation and `linux` as your terminal type.

Comment: Good stuff. The `1/2` character is still there, but the `;?;?` is gone now. Anyone think this is a vim bug? SecureCRT bug? General terminal emulation problem? PuTTY doesn't show these characters.

Comment: These things are almost always a mismatch between telling applications that you are using XTerm and then using something _that is not XTerm_ such as SecureCRT.  PuTTY people experience problems too when they don't use `putty` or `putty-256color` as their terminal type.  There are plenty of examples of that on this WWW site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the SecureCRT character encoding in `Session > Properties > Terminal > Appearance` from `Default` to `UTF-8` fixed the problem.

Also, changing the SecureCRT `Session > Properties > Terminal > Emulation > Terminal` from `Xterm` to `Linux` also fixed the problem, but with a 16-color terminal restriction.